# Unable to display images in Gridview using fragment

Tags: android, gridview, fragment

I am new to Android and currently want to create a fragment to display gridview layout.However I not able to display images and return error below:

```
      java.lang.NullPointerException
      at miui.util.AttributeResolver.i(SourceFile:35)
      at miui.util.AttributeResolver.resolveInt(SourceFile:145)
      at miui.util.AttributeResolver.isUsingMiuiTheme(SourceFile:179)
      at miui.os.Environment.isUsingMiui(SourceFile:99)
      at android.view.ViewConfigurationInjector.get(ViewConfigurationInjector.java:18)
      at android.view.ViewConfigurationHelper.get(ViewConfigurationHelper.java:10)
      at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:357)
      at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3452)
      at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:114)
      at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.GridViewAdapter.getView(GridViewAdapter.java:52)
      at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2257)
```

Below is my Fragment code

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
public HomeFragment(){}
private GridViewAdapter adapter;
private GridView gridView;
private int columnWidth;
private Utils utils;
private PrefManager pref;
private Integer[] photosList;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    gridView = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
    gridView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity()));
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Below is my gridview adapter code

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int imageWidth;
    private Context context;

    public GridViewAdapter(Activity activity) {
        this._activity=activity;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.photoList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_photo, null);
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(photoList[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    public Integer[] photoList = {

            R.drawable.ic_whats_hot, R.drawable.ic_home,
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_communities,
            R.drawable.ic_people, R.drawable.ic_whats_hot
    };
}
```

The error line shows that my line have problem when getting Image from Context, may advise?

```
imageView = new ImageView(context);
```

Comment: Are u creating imageview dynamically? Or u  want to use the imageview in your layout

Comment: line 52 -imageView = new ImageView(context);

Comment: Your context  object is null. Can you try with _activity

Comment: @playmaker420, I want to create a simple gridview layout which display images in 2 columns only

Comment: @playmaker420, Thank you. It works now with _activity. would like to ask why we cannot use context?

Comment: because in your constructor u  havent initialized the context object

Comment: @playmaker420, thank you. I have better understanding in Context now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your context object is null.
as you have context of your activity. so use this

```
imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is your context that is coming back as null, we need to provide an argument that isn't null. Some common classes which provide a context are Activity, Application, Service and View. In line 9, you initialize an Activity object _activity.

Since this object has context, you can use it in place of "context."

```
imageView = new ImageView(_activity);
```

Comment: Thank you @John Riggs for your explaination and knowledge sharing on context. I have better understanding on context now.

Answer (score 0):

You are using not initialized context.

Please use _activity that parsed via GridViewAdapter from the HomeFragment.

Error is your "context" has never been initialized in your GridViewAdapter.

Replace as  `imageView = new ImageView(_activity);`